# What python web interaction module should be used for https?

Tags: python

What python web interaction module should be used for https operations?
Such as a program that automatically registers accounts on a HTTPS/SSL certificate protected website.

Answer (score 3):

Not really sure what you're asking here, but the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module is excellent for all kinds of HTTP operations, including HTTPS.